# BitTorrent etiquette with multiple nodes

Tags: bittorrent

I have two BitTorrent nodes running, one of which is on a limited data connection. I know you're supposed to leave the node running long enough for it to upload as much as it has downloaded, but is it okay to close the one on the limited connection early if I leave the unlimited one running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really doesn't matter how many nodes you have running as long as you're seeding. As for etiquette, there's basically only goodwill on your side, no requirements or obligations at all.